# Ember Fastboot monitor debug tool

Tags: javascript, ember.js, fastboot

I have a Fastboot application running on Docker and lately containers have been consuming a lot of CPU and RAM on the server. Is it possible to monitor what is causing this in Fastboot? Any plugins or services to monitor?

Tool to monitor ember fastboot and the processes that consume the most CPU and application calls that take the most time.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of Fastboot-specifc tools to do this.

But Fastboot is a pretty thin middleware mounted in a Node (Express) app. So Express and Node profiling tools should be applicable. Surely it's possible to get Flame charts and heap information with a Node profiler.

We use NewRelic with Node VM monitoring on a Fastboot app which  gives good info about system resource use. This allows us to compare across app deployments.

It's possible that your app has memory leaks in which case [ember-cli-memory-leak-detector](https://github.com/steveszc/ember-cli-memory-leak-detector) might be useful.

However, my intuition (and experience with Fastboot processes) is that the whole system isn't that efficient (we do a lot of caching). Our processes are quite resource-hungry.